# Generate vector of linearly spaced growth rates, knowing beginning, end, and total compounded growth, with numpy or similar

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, math, vector

I'm looking to model discrete growth rates for a biology application.  I know the starting growth rate per hr (200%) and the ending growth rate per hr (2%).  The growth rate should decrease linearly every hour.  I also know that the total growth should be 200x.  I'm trying to calculate the number of hours required and generate a vector array, sized to the number of hours, containing the growth rates (one value per hr)... something like [200%, 180%, 160% ... 4%, 2%].  But I need the total compounded growth to equal 200x.

I've played with np.linspace and np.geomspace, but I'm not smart enough to know how to get the compounded growth to match in this case.

Comment: Coming from academia, "I'm not smart enough" and other deference is usually a way to get someone to do the work for you. Please show what you've tried and what went wrong with your attempts.

Comment: Are those growth rates instantaneous growth rates, i.e. derivative values, or are they discrete? What is the time unit for those growth rates, e.g. starting at 200% per hour, per day, per year or other?

Comment: They are discrete.  200% per hour.

Comment: @roganjosh

I've tried the following...
I calculated the arithmetic mean growth rate to be (200% + 2%) / 2 = 101%.  I then calculated the number of hours to be math.log(200, 1 + 1.01) ~= 7.59.  The compounded mean growth rate must be 200^(1/7.59) - 1 = 100.98%.

That's where I get stuck...

I tried growth_rates = np.linspace(2, 0.02, 7) but of course when I do np.cumprod(1 + growth_rates) to check, the answer is not 200

Comment: More clarification needed. Is the number of hours to be integral? If so, you cannot hit exactly 200x growth, so do you want the growth just below or just above 200x? Is the meaning of the discrete growth rates that in the entire first hour the growth rate is 200% so at the end of the first hour you now have 3x the original amount, then the growth rate drops immediately to 101% (say) for the full second hour, and so on? Is the final 2% growth rate effective for a full hour or is it reached and immediately the experiment is done?

Comment: Also, your example growth rates are `200%, 180%, 160%`, showing a 20% drop per hour, but the example ends with `4%, 2%`, a 2% drop per hour. Did you mean something more like `[200%, 180.2%, 160.4%, 140.6%, 120.8%, 101%, 81.2%, 61.4%, 41.6%, 21.8%, 2%]`? Or perhaps `[200%, 178%, 156%, 134%, 112%, 90%, 68%, 46%, 24%, 2%]`?

Comment: @RoryDaulton: thanks.  The number hours must be integral, so I guess it would be ok to slightly exceed or miss the 200x (want to get as close as possible).  Yes, the growth rate drops each hour.  So if it is [200%, 180%, 160%], a value starting at 1 at time 0, would be 3 at 1hr, 3*2.8 at 2hr, and so forth.  Ideally, it would hit 200x right before the growth drops to 2%, but it would be ok if the last growth rate is 2% as well (not a big difference to me).  You are right.. the example sequence would be more like the first that you described (although the second would be interesting as well).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for your problem. The assumptions are that the growth rate is 200% from the beginning of the first hour to the end of the first hour, meaning it goes from a value to 3 times its value. Then the growth from the beginning to the end of the second hour drops to a lower rate, and so on. The growth rate from the beginning to the end of the final hour is 2%, and the rates drop linearly--i.e. the rates are a decreasing arithmetic progression.

This code finds the lowest number of integral hours for the final amount to be at least 200 times the initial amount. I am not a numpy expert, so I calculate the overall growths using a regular Python loop rather than using numpy.

```
import numpy as np

start_growth_rate = 2.00  # 200% as a decimal
stop_growth_rate = 0.02  # 2% as a decimal
target_total_growth = 200  # 200 times larger than the starting value

calced_total_growth = 0
num_hours = 2
while calced_total_growth < target_total_growth:
    rates_array = np.linspace(start=start_growth_rate, stop=stop_growth_rate,
                              num=num_hours)
    calced_total_growth = 1
    for this_growth_rate in rates_array:
        calced_total_growth *= 1 + this_growth_rate
    num_hours += 1

print('Actual total growth rate = {} times over {} hours.'.format(
        calced_total_growth, num_hours - 1))
print('Growths = {}'.format(rates_array))
```

The printed output is

```
Actual total growth rate = 324.01866418570273 times over 9 hours.
Growths = [ 2.      1.7525  1.505   1.2575  1.01    0.7625  0.515   0.2675  0.02  ]
```

The final result is over `324`, much more than your target of 200. If you reduce the hour to only 8 you get

```
Actual total growth rate = 168.09849392178677 times over 8 hours.
Growths = [ 2.          1.71714286  1.43428571  1.15142857  0.86857143  0.58571429
  0.30285714  0.02      ]
```

which is lower than your target of 200 but closer than using one more hour.

Using the 9-hour rates, the target of 200 is actually crossed during the next-to-last hour. The exact time it is crossed depends on how you model the growth pattern from the beginning of that hour to the end--that growth within the hour is irrelevant to my assumptions and to my code.

---

Another set of assumptions is also possible--the growth rates you give are instantaneous, and the goal of 200x does not happen in an integral number of hours. The solution here is more mathematical, but here is an outline.

If we let T be the time needed to reach a population size 200 times the initial value. Then to descend linearly from 2 to 0.02 in time `T` the formula for the growth rate `y` at time `t` is

```
y'/y = 2 - (1.98 / T) * t
```

This is a separable differential equation, with the initial condition y(0)=1. Solving that has the solution

```
y = exp(2 * t - (0.99 / T) * t**2)
```

in Python syntax. Since we want to end at the target 200 at time T, we get

```
T = log(200) / 1.01 = 5.245858778760432
```

where logarithm is the natural logarithm and that last value is approximate. So the final solution for the population function is

```
y = exp(2 * t - (0.9999 / log(200)) * t**2)
```

But what you want in your printed array are the growth rates, given by

```
y'/y = 2 - (1.9998 / log(200)) * t
```

which are approximately shown in the array

```
[2 - (1.9998 / log(200)) * t for t in range(6)]
```

which evaluates to

```
[2.0,
 1.622559416197654,
 1.2451188323953077,
 0.8676782485929615,
 0.4902376647906155,
 0.11279708098826946]
```

The last value is not 0.02 because the growth continues a little past hour 5. (See time T above for the actual ending time.)

Comment: Thanks very much!  I guess I should've realized the integral constraint would be so limiting.  yes I would love to see the instantaneous solution.  Would it be possible to represent the instantaneous solution in a discrete form, where the last time array value represents an hourly growth rate but takes place over a fraction of an hour?  That way it can still be stored in a discrete hourly array.  So, if the last value is 2% and we know the hours is 8.42 for example, the last multiplication would be cumulative * 1.02^(0.42)

Comment: @bamboo77: See my last edit for the instantaneous solution.

Comment: Thanks again Rory.  I may not be understanding this correctly, but should e^(2 + 1.62256 + 1.24512 + 0.86768 + 0.49024 + 0.02) equal 200?  It seems to go over that

Comment: @bamboo77: The growth rates for that section of my answer are instantaneous, so the growth is near-exponential at any instant and what you wrote is not how to find the values. The formula for the population is `y = exp(2 * t - (0.9999 / log(200)) * t**2)` and if you substitute `5.245858778760432` for t you get the final population `199.99999999999991` which is `200` with slight rounding error. You won't understand instantaneous growth rates if you haven't studied calculus. You get the population values by integration, not what you wrote.